# Loading an image from Disk to used to replace a source image for an image object

Tags: unity, c#

I am working on a Unity project where I need to be able to grab an image from disk and then have it be replaced as the source image for an image gameobject. Currently I already have a filebrowser implemented that gives me the filepath.

```
if (File.Exists(output)){
    GameOjbect imageselect = GameObject.Find("ImageSelection");
    imageselect.GetComponent<Image>();
    //I need to make the file location at path output be the sprite?/sourceimage? for imageselect
}
```

Sorry if this has already been asked, I have been looking at other examples this morning with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Texture2D.LoadImage](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.LoadImage.html) to load your image into a Texture2D, assuming it's a PNG or JPG image.

The method takes in a `byte[]`, so you'll have to use `File.ReadAllBytes(output)`.

Something like this:

```
if (File.Exists(output))
{
    var fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(output);
    var texture2D = new Texture2D(2, 2);

    if (texture2D.LoadImage(fileBytes))
    {
        _image.sprite = Sprite.Create(texture2D,
                                      new Rect(0, 0, texture2D.width, texture2D.height),
                                      new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f));
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogError("Error when loading file as Texture2D!");
    }
}
```

should work just fine.

The `Texture2D.LoadImage()` method will automatically resize the 2x2 texture2D object depending on the file loaded.

There's also an optional fourth parameter for `Sprite.Create()` that takes in a float pixelsPerUnit.

Comment: You can also use [the WWW class](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) to asynchronously load an image from a local or network location. You can then access the image as a Texture2D by reading the `.texture` property of your www object.

Comment: Is it also possible to replace a source image that is used by a unity gameobject this way? I want to replace the slice that is used in a sprite renderer and in an animation clip by setting a different source image.